# Alocação dinamica com struct

Tags: c, c++, struct, alocação, gerenciamento-de-memória

```
/*  [Error] expected primary-expression before'*' token
    [Error] 'dia' was not declared in this scope
    [Error] 'mes' was not declared in this scope
    [Error] 'ano' was not declared in this scope
*/
```

Esta dando no compilador estes erros. Acho que declarei errado algo ou ainda não compreendi direito a alocação dinâmica alguém pode me ajudar

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main ()
{   
 struct calendario
 {
 int dia;
 int mes;
 int ano;
 };
 struct calendario x,*ptr;
ptr= malloc(calendario * sizeof(int));
  ptr->dia = 5;
  ptr->mes=10;
  ptr->ano=1990;
   printf("%i",dia);
   printf("%i", mes);
   printf("%i",ano);
system("pause>null");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De fato a alocação da `struct`não se faz assim. Deve-se pegar o tamanho dela, sei lá porque está pegando o tamanho de um `int` se quer alocar a estrutura. E a multiplicação só faz sentido se for alocar várias instâncias das estrutura.

Também havia um erro na hora de imprimir que tentava acessar os membros sem a variável que eles estão. Também eliminei a variável `x`, não usada.

Não mudei outras coisas que ficariam melhor porque ainda está aprendendo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {   
    struct calendario {
        int dia;
        int mes;
        int ano;
    };
    struct calendario *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct calendario));
    ptr->dia = 5;
    ptr->mes = 10;
    ptr->ano = 1990;
    printf("%i/%i/%i", ptr->dia, ptr->mes, ptr->ano);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HQBklX). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/iwosbhqr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Allocation.c).

Comment: bigown voce me indica algum site ou livro para que eu possa estudaar , quero aprender muito sobre isso e dominar esse assunto, para poder ajudar a comunidade e meus colegas de classe.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info. Agora você já pode votar em tudo no site, não só nas coisas que perguntou. Pode aprender com o que tem aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c?sort=votes&pageSize=50