# Como declarar uma variável de data em C?

Tags: c, c++, funções, struct, tipagem

Preciso criar um tipo abstrato de dados que represente uma
pessoa, contendo nome, data de nascimento e CPF, e criar
uma variável que é um ponteiro para este TAD (no
programa principal).

Até certo ponto eu sei, mas não sei qual é o tipo adequado para colocar no lugar do "?".

```
struct pessoa
{
    char nome;
    double cpf;
    ?   Data_Nasc;
}x,*ptr;
ptr = &x;
```

Comment: Está recebendo sua introdução a Estruturas de Dados em C? Boa sorte. :)

Comment: Achei que você queria um tipo de data, não enfiar a data de qualquer jeito na estrutura. Acho que realmente precisa ler o material que te passei. Isso é gambi.

Comment: vou atras do material que me passo bigown o que eu tenho que fazer ainda nao acabou, eu tenho que fazer essa struct e depois passar ela para uma função , na função ela deve ser preenchida e devo ter outra função que imprime o que foi preenchido em na primeira função . eu vou tentar estudar, por que ainda nao sei fazer essas manobras com as funções e o que aprender vo incrementar no meu codigo, se nao rodar vo procura ajudar com a comunidade aqui

Comment: CPF como `double` == problemas quando o CPF começar com zero ;)

Comment: eu mudei para char o cpf assim como o bigown me falou e agora compreendo porque nao posso fazer no tipo double obrigado renan em sala de aula ja vi minha professora usando esse tipo para cpf vou fala para ela sobre isso

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solução apontada pelo colega @Maniero, do ponto de vista de abstração de dados é válida, porém, ele reinventou a roda, pois a biblioteca padrão já possui todas as abstrações de data e hora e todas as funções necessárias para manipulá-las.

O mais adequado para substituir a `?` seria o tipo `time_t` definido pela biblioteca padrão `time.h`. Este tipo representa a quantidade de segundos que se passou desde a data de 1 de janeiro de 1970 às 00:00:00 (UTC), é considerado o marco zero do sistema de calendário usado pelos computadores.

> Apesar do calendário gregoriano facilitar o raciocínio cronológico
>   para os humanos, quando se deseja realizar comparações lógicas ou
>   cálculos com datas em computadores, este tipo de calendário acaba
>   dificultando o trabalho.
>
> Por exemplo, para nós, saber o que aconteceu primeiro, se foi algo em
>   10/04/1977 12:45:15 ou algo em 10/03/1976 13:09:12 é algo quase
>   automático mas para resolver isso em um computador todos os 6 campos
>   teriam que ser analisados independentemente, apesar disso ser
>   realizado quase que instantâneamente não deixa de ser um trabalho
>   extra que o processador poderia evitar se fizesse uso de outro formato
>   de data. Imaginemos um banco de dados com milhares de registros e o
>   processador recebendo um comando para colocar tudo em ordem
>   cronológica, se pudermos fazer as comparações com uma única operação
>   por registro ao invés de 6 operações/registro o tempo final também
>   tenderá a ser 6 vezes menor.

O exemplo a seguir ilustra a conversão de um valor do tipo `time_t` para uma data e hora humanamente legível:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    time_t agora;
    char datahora[100];

    /* Recupera a quantidade de segundos desde 01/01/1970 */
    agora = time(NULL);

    /* Formata a data e a hora da forma desejada */
    strftime( datahora, sizeof(datahora), "%d.%m.%Y - %H:%M:%S", localtime( &agora ) );

    printf( "Data/Hora: %s\n", datahora );

    return 0;
}
```

Já esté outro, ilustra como ler uma data e hora em formato humano para a quantidade de segundos desde o marco zero:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

char datahora[] = "01.01.2016 - 12:00:00";  

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    struct tm tm; 
    int ano, mes; 

    sscanf( datahora, "%d.%d.%d - %d:%d:%d", &tm.tm_mday, &mes, &ano, &tm.tm_hour, &tm.tm_min, &tm.tm_sec );

    tm.tm_year = ano - 1900;
    tm.tm_mon = mes - 1;

    printf( "Segundos desde 01/01/1970: %ld\n", mktime( &tm ) );

    return 0;
}
```

A melhor parte é quando precisamos comparar datas, podemos usar operadores de comparação, da mesma forma que comparamos inteiros:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

char datahora1[] = "12.01.2000 - 12:00:00"; 
char datahora2[] = "01.01.2015 - 13:10:20";  

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    time_t t1;
    time_t t2;

    struct tm tm; 
    int ano, mes; 

    sscanf( datahora1, "%d.%d.%d - %d:%d:%d", &tm.tm_mday, &mes, &ano, &tm.tm_hour, &tm.tm_min, &tm.tm_sec );

    tm.tm_year = ano - 1900;
    tm.tm_mon = mes - 1;

    t1 = mktime( &tm );

    sscanf( datahora2, "%d.%d.%d - %d:%d:%d", &tm.tm_mday, &mes, &ano, &tm.tm_hour, &tm.tm_min, &tm.tm_sec );

    tm.tm_year = ano - 1900;
    tm.tm_mon = mes - 1;

    t2 = mktime( &tm );

    if( t1 < t2 )
    {
        printf( "Data1 esta antes de Data2!\n");
    }
    else if( t1 > t2 )
    {
        printf( "Data1 esta depois Data2!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Data1 eh iguaal a Data2!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 13):

Você não faz isto. C não é uma linguagem que facilita tanto as abstrações. Claro que nada impede você de criar um tipo para guardar e manipular datas, como fez em sua [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126779/101). Ainda que o nome, provavelmente estrutura não fossem adequados e não tenha funções auxiliares para manipular a estrutura, é basicamente isto o que deve ser feito: crie uma estrutura, que é um tipo composto por membros, e use isto dentro de outra estrutura quando necessário.

Fora isto pode usar um tipo de alguma biblioteca pronta, mas para fins de aprendizado não acho adequado.

Uma base sem querer ser completo, otimizado ao máximo, seria:

```
typedef struct {
    int ano;
    short mes;
    short dia;
} Data
struct pessoa {
    char nome;
    double cpf;
    Data data_nasc;
} x,*ptr;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Date.c).

Não entendi muito bem porque usar `double` como CPF. O correto seria um `char *` ou `char[12]`, mas na pior das hipóteses, se ainda não aprendeu mexer com isto, ser um `long`. O nome também está errado, ou teria que ser [um ponteiro ou um *array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101). Do jeito que está só permite 1 caractere no nome.

Comment: para criar uma função que preencha essas duas estruturas, eu devo declarar :

Comment: func1(ptr,data);

Comment: fun1(int *ptr, int data ){
};

Comment: eu ja arrumei a variavel nome para char nome[20];

Comment: bigown arrumei o post para que voce entenda.

Comment: tem algo que eu precise arrumar ?

Comment: Você não pode mudar a pergunta, tem que fazer novas. Vou reverter a edição.

Answer (score 1):

Note que não é necessário que cada dado seja mapeado para uma variável da sua estrutura. Com isso em mente, uma solução simples é ter uma variável para dia, outra para o mês mais uma para o ano de nascimento.

```
struct pessoa
{
    char nome;
    double cpf;
    int dia_de_nascimento;
    int mes_de_nascimento;
    int ano_de_nascimento;
}
```

Uma observação: o tipo do campo `nome` da sua estrutura provavelmente está errado, a não ser que seu programa aceite apenas nomes de um caractere.

Comment: pablo percebi meus erros ao postar, em outro post eu tentarei ser mais direto ao assunto obrigado

Answer (score 1):

C tem um tipo de dados que guarda datas. O Uilque mencionou a biblioteca na resposta dele (time.h). Segue a documentação oficial em português:

http://pt.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm

Tem um exemplo de como obter uma data atual no [original em inglês](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct tm start = {.tm_mday=1};
    mktime(&start);
    printf("%s\n", asctime(&start));
}
```

Se você está fazendo isso para aprender por conta própria, sugiro começar por uma linguagem mais fácil como C#, Java ou Javascript (a menos que você já as domine e queira realmente mergulhar em C). Agora, se isso é para uma tarefa de colégio ou faculdade... Seu professor é um louco ou carrasco. Continue a estudar para passar, mas tente aprender uma linguagem mais fácil como as que eu mencionei. As estruturas de data e hora nessas linguagens são bem mais fáceis de usar para quem está no começo.

Comment: pois e renan e uma tarefa de faculdade e apenas o exercicio 3 de 4

Comment: Este e o exercicio que eu tenho que fazer ...
/*Criar um tipo abstrato de dados que represente uma
pessoa, contendo nome, data de nascimento e CPF. Crie
uma variável que é um ponteiro para este TAD (no
programa principal). Depois crie uma função que receba
este ponteiro e preencha os dados da estrutura e também
uma uma função que receba este ponteiro e imprima os
dados da estrutura. Finalmente, faça a chamada a esta
função na função principal.   */

Estou aos poucos tentando fazer no que eu tenho duvida eu posto aqui para a comunidade me ajudar.

Comment: Hm... A menos que o professor se oponha, eu usaria uma string pra representar a data. Mais simples e o problema fica resolvido por enquanto. Quando você realmente precisar fazer operações com datas (ver se o ano é bissexto, pegar a data daqui a X dias a partir de hoje etc.) é que você deve se preocupar com essas estruturas mais avançadas. Vai por mim, preserve sua sanidade e passe na cadeira agora, aprenda como usar datas profissionalmente depois.

Comment: verdade e uma boa ideia renan, o meu professor esta mais preocupado se conseguimos usar bem as funções, eu posso fazer isso que voce disse irei mudar meu codigo e transformar minha data numa string

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com esse exemplo na [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_date_and_time_functions#Example), seria algo como:

```
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    time_t dataEHorario;

    // Você ainda pode setar a data para o atual do sistema
    current_time = time(NULL);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: bigown aprendo muito com voce obrigado, estou sempre de olho naqueles links que voce me passo, me solucionou algumas duvidas.
Bigown caso eu queira usar uma função para preencher essa struct eu devo passar como parametro o ponteiro certo ?

Comment: Uilque ajudo muito, concerteza era uma duvida que futuramente eu teria.

Comment: @ALFAEX como você não achou a minha uma boa solução, é irrelevante, mas poderia ter uma função para fazer isto, também poderia fazer *inline*. Quando for escrever para a pessoa usae o `@` antes do nome (ele até ajuda preencher) e faça na resposta da pesoa, assim ela é notificada, eu vi aqui por acaso.

Comment: desculpe me perco ainda nas ações que tomo no site, a sua solução e a mais completa, so que eu ainda nao sei manipular esses dados eu vou estudar o que e typedef, eu vi apenas alguns topicos sobre nunca me aprofundei. Tenho duvidas de como se comporta o codigo .

Comment: @ALFAEX vai perguntando que a gente vai ajudando.

Comment: perguntando aqui nos comentarios ou criando tags ?