# Como utilizar datas em C?

Tags: c

Queria saber como implementar a biblioteca `time.h`

A aplicação deve identificar o cliente, a data inicio e fim
do aluguer, e preço pago pelo aluguer e a data pagamento.

Temos as seguintes estruturas:

```
typedef struct Aluguer

    struct tm data_inicio;                  
    struct tm data_fim;                     
    int preco;                         
    struct tm data_pagamento;               
    int pagaEfetuado; // -- 0 -> não pago || 1 -> pago
}ALUGUER;



typedef struct Elem{

  ALUGUER node;

  struct Elem *seguinte;

}ELEMENTO;
```

O exercício pede-nos para listar todos os veículos disponíveis para alugar para um determinado período (intervalo de datas).

Como deveria proceder?

Comment: Aqui há uma referência de como usar a biblioteca time.h

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/

Comment: Isto? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/126795/101

Comment: "como implementar a biblioteca time.h" - como assim ? A biblioteca já existe e tem várias coisas definidas, tal como a `struct tm` que está a utilizar no seu código. Como vão ser as datas definidas na sua aplicação ?